# Reload CSS in Eclipse RCP Application

Tags: css, eclipse, themes, rcp

I try design a CSS for my app rcp in eclipse 3.6, but i need refresh or reload applicationCSS attribute (in command o event), I don't use Theme, I only use the applicationCSS attribute in my product definition, with default theme.

Comment: `applicationCSS` is for Eclipse 4.x not 3.6

Comment: Ok, but how to reload or refresh this reference

Comment: If you mean reload the CSS file I am not aware of any API to do that.